# Am getting bad request 400 while uploading files after 60 seconds

Tags: php

Am trying to upload files to a remote host and am getting a 400 bad request after **60 seconds of upload** i don't know if its a session problem or a firewall problem. The code works fine in my localhost and other server

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select file to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload file" name="submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>

// upload.php file

<?php
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
?>

<?php
$target_dir = "docs/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;

if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    if (file_exists($target_file)) {
        echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }      

    if ($uploadOk == 0) {
        echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
    } else {
    // if condition to check if the file has been uploaded or not
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
          echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
        }else {
          echo "Upload failed";
        }
      }
}
?>
```

**php.ini** file content:

```
display_errors = On
max_execution_time = 300
max_input_time = 300
max_input_vars = 8000
memory_limit = 256M
post_max_size = 192M
session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440
session.save_path = "/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php73"
upload_max_filesize = 256M
zlib.output_compression = Off
```

the hosting support said that they tested the server and everything is working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by splitting the file and uploading it by pieces using [blob.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/slice)